# How to log in multiple share drive and save the username and password all at once?

Tags: windows, sharepoint, cmd, server, automation

I have bunch of IP address (1000++).

And I need to use a programming tool to log in to ever server (which I have never entered before)  and extract the data.

How can I one shot enter all of the username and password of all share drive in my computer? Need help...

[image]

Comment: Do you want to copy data from all the servers and firstly you need to map a share? Like this? https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/DriveMapAdd.htm

Comment: hey @Xenobiologist , ermm, I not want to map the drive, but just to log in all the share drive once (so that later the program able to access into it) , do you get what I mean?

Comment: You are looking for [WNetAddConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2a)